# json generation is incorrect using struts2 json plugin for camelCase fields

Tags: java, json, reflection, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

```
private Integer iDisplayLength ;

public Integer getIDisplayLength() {
        return iDisplayLength;
    }

    public void setIDisplayLength(Integer iDisplayLength) {
        this.iDisplayLength = iDisplayLength;
    }
```

If the request contains `iDisplayLength`, it's set perfectly and I can see the value in action. But when the response returns (json-response) then it returns

`IDisplayLength` instead of `iDisplayLength`

Seems like a bug to me. Am I doing it wrong ? Are those getters & setters incorrect ?

My struts.xml looks like :

```
<action name="c/list" class="actions.MyAction" method="list">
            <result name="*" type="json"></result>
</action>
```

**Update**

I went through the plugin source code at : https://github.com/apache/struts2/blob/STRUTS_2_3_15_X/plugins/json/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/json/JSONWriter.java

After replicating the method it uses to figure out a fields' name :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class clazz = new IoAction().getClass();

        BeanInfo info = getBeanInfoIgnoreHierarchy(clazz);

        PropertyDescriptor[] props = info.getPropertyDescriptors();

        boolean hasData = false;
        for (PropertyDescriptor prop : props) {
            System.out.println("Field Name : "+prop.getName());
        }
    }
```

In `IoAction` there are getters/setters like :

```
public String getISortCol_0() {
        return iSortCol_0;
    }

    public void setISortCol_0(String iSortCol_0) {
        this.iSortCol_0 = iSortCol_0;
    }
```

And the above code prints Field Name as `ISortCol_0` which is incorrect (IMHO), it should have returned `iSortCol_0` Is it a bug in the java reflection API ?